# How to clone a table and keep structure in sync in Rails app?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

I have a table with a lot of records, so I encountered with slow SQL queries. The thing is that I'm using **act_as_paranoid** gem and there is no hard delete of records, only soft with marking "deleted" records with **deleted_at** timestamp. I don't wanna totally remove such records, because I need them for statistics.

My plan is to move "deleted" records to another table which will has the same structure. So the question is:  **in terms of rails, how to clone a table  (without a data) and keep structure in sync**. I don't want to duplicate migration and model.

Comment: Study [Partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning.html). Especially partition pruning.

Comment: Looks like a solution, thx.

Comment: @Akina Can't find how to split by null and not null values

Comment: Provide more info about current structure (and show 2-3 sample rows, may skip excess columns). In general split by null and not null values needed close to never, but if it is needed really then you may try to partition by expression or by generated column.

Comment: @Akina quick example. I have 800k records with delete_at column is not null, and 100k records with deleted_at null. SQL query looks like ***select * from real_estate where price < 10000***. With this number of total rows it running for ~2 secs. But when I'll have ~100k records it should be much faster. I simplified query a lot, in real conditions there are a lot of other fields that might exists on not.

Comment: Your query is not relative to `deleted_at` column and hence it can be really improved by decreasing total rows amount in the table (without decreasing the rows amount returned) only if you have no index by `price` and server needs in the table scan. The example seems to me unsuccessful.

Comment: Also you may partition by RANGe using an expression `COALESCE(deleted_at, 'literal')` where the literal is a date in far past (to move these rows into 1st partition) or far future (to move them to the last, LESS THAN MAXVALUE, partition).

Comment: @Akina It's a hell. I was trying to do it like you propose, but getting `A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function (prefixed columns are not considered).`. After some investigation I realized that I have to add UNIQUE index for deleted_at column. But I can't, because such column has non unique values

Comment: Bad. Partitioning is not applicable in your case...

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing it with pure SQL. This will do what you want:

CREATE TABLE new_tbl LIKE orig_tbl;

Also you can go through this document, since it helps in learning partitioning.